# how to load a dependency pick-list values by using force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dependent-picklist

I have created a custom component for creating, edit records. in that i have a dependency pick list values. now i want to display values on load of record.here is my code. please correct me.

**Component:**

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">                     
                    <lightning:select name="controllerFld" value="{!v.simpleNewRule.Asset_Type__c}" label="Asset Type" onchange="{!c.onControllerFieldChange}" aura:id="InputAssetType">      
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listControllingValues}" var="val">
                            <option value="{!val}">{!val}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                </div>

                <!--Dependent Field-->
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-3">
                    <lightning:select name="dependentFld" value="{!v.simpleNewRule.Case_Type__c}" label="Case Type" disabled="{!v.bDisabledDependentFld}" aura:id="InputCaseType">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.listDependingValues}" var="val">
                            <option value="{!val}">{!val}</option>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </lightning:select>
                </div>
```

**JS:**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) { 
    // get the fields API name and pass it to helper function  
    var controllingFieldAPI = component.get("v.controllingFieldAPI");
    var dependingFieldAPI = component.get("v.dependingFieldAPI");
    var objDetails = component.get("v.objDetail");
    // call the helper function
    helper.fetchPicklistValues(component,objDetails,controllingFieldAPI, dependingFieldAPI);
},
   // For Dependency Picklist Values.
onControllerFieldChange: function(component, event, helper) {     
    var controllerValueKey = event.getSource().get("v.value"); // get selected controller field value
    var depnedentFieldMap = component.get("v.depnedentFieldMap");

    if (controllerValueKey != '--- None ---') {
        var ListOfDependentFields = depnedentFieldMap[controllerValueKey];

        if(ListOfDependentFields.length > 0){
            component.set("v.bDisabledDependentFld" , false);  
            helper.fetchDepValues(component, ListOfDependentFields);    
        }else{
            component.set("v.bDisabledDependentFld" , true); 
            component.set("v.listDependingValues", ['--- None ---']);
        }  

    } else {
        component.set("v.listDependingValues", ['--- None ---']);
        component.set("v.bDisabledDependentFld" , true);
    }
},
```

**Helper:**

```
        // For Dependency Picklist Values
  fetchPicklistValues: function(component,objDetails,controllerField, dependentField) {
    // call the server side function  
    var action = component.get("c.getDependentMap");
    // pass paramerters [object definition , contrller field name ,dependent field name] -
    // to server side function 
    action.setParams({
        'objDetail' : objDetails,
        'contrfieldApiName': controllerField,
        'depfieldApiName': dependentField 
    });
    //set callback   
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if (response.getState() == "SUCCESS") {
            //store the return response from server (map<string,List<string>>)  
            var StoreResponse = response.getReturnValue();

            // once set #StoreResponse to depnedentFieldMap attribute 
            component.set("v.depnedentFieldMap",StoreResponse);

            // create a empty array for store map keys(@@--->which is controller picklist values) 
            var listOfkeys = []; // for store all map keys (controller picklist values)
            var ControllerField = []; // for store controller picklist value to set on lightning:select. 

            // play a for loop on Return map 
            // and fill the all map key on listOfkeys variable.
            for (var singlekey in StoreResponse) {
                listOfkeys.push(singlekey);
            }

            //set the controller field value for lightning:select
            if (listOfkeys != undefined && listOfkeys.length > 0) {
                ControllerField.push('--- None ---');
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < listOfkeys.length; i++) {
                ControllerField.push(listOfkeys[i]);
            }  
            // set the ControllerField variable values to country(controller picklist field)
            component.set("v.listControllingValues", ControllerField);
        }else{
            //alert('Something went wrong..');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

fetchDepValues: function(component, ListOfDependentFields) {
    // create a empty array var for store dependent picklist values for controller field  
    var dependentFields = [];
    dependentFields.push('--- None ---');
    for (var i = 0; i < ListOfDependentFields.length; i++) {
        dependentFields.push(ListOfDependentFields[i]);
    }
    // set the dependentFields variable values to store(dependent picklist field) on lightning:select
    component.set("v.listDependingValues", dependentFields);

},
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Salesforce UI API to get dependent picklist values . https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/01/introduction-salesforce-ui-api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried **lightning:recordEditForm** ?

It fetches all Picklist data (Dependent ones too) and other metadata. It is using **Salesforce UI API** under the hood.

Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/example

Answer (score 1):

On record load, `onControllerFieldChange` will not call automatically. To get dependent Picklist values you need to manually call that function after record load.